# Adding multiple columns with default value (Teradata)

Tags: teradata, ddl

I tried to search but I have not found anything. I am trying to add two columns to a table withe a default value (Teradata). I am trying with this statement

```
ALTER TABLE TEST 
add (DWH_Change_dt date  default CURRENT_DATE, dwh_create_dt date  default current_date);
```

This does not work with default clause. I get this error

Syntax error, expected something like a 'BETWEEN' keyword or an 'IN' keyword or a 'LIKE' keyword or a 'CONTAINS' keyword between the word 'DWH_Change_dt' and the 'date'

If I add one column at a time it works (without parenthesis). Anyone has any idea? What is wrong?

Thanks,
Umberto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add multiple columns you need multiple ADDs:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST 
add DWH_Change_dt date  default CURRENT_DATE, 
add dwh_create_dt date  default current_date;
```